# Why am I unable to send the charge to Stripe and my Strapi.js backend using a try/catch in my React frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch, stripe-payments, strapi

I am trying to send a charge to stripe. I have a charge set up in my Strapi.js backend as well as a new order being created. I have created a function in my react frontend to create an entry to my 'orders' content type in strapi but it seems as though nothing in the function's try/catch is working, it is not even logging an error.

I've attempted to make change some variables here and there, but im honestly a little overwhelmed because this is the first time im using these technologies and I am somewhat of a beginner. I was somewhat watching a video for guidance through some things but this is where I faced issues. I am bringing in the script tag in the index.html file as well. I am using strapi sdk.

Here is what the create Orders function on the strapi backend looks like(stripe is being brought in at top of page using secret key):

```
create: async (ctx) => {
    const { address, city, products, amount, token } = ctx.request.body;

    // Stripe Charge
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount * 100,
      currency: 'usd',
      description: `Order ${new Date(Date.now())}`,
      source: token
    });

    const order = await strapi.services.orders.add({
      address,
      city,
      products,
      amount,
    });

    return order;

 }
```

Here is my submit function in react frontend checkout.js file

```
 handleOrder = async () => {
        const { checkOutItems, city, address } = this.state;
        let token;
        const amount = calculateTotalAmount(checkOutItems);
        // console.log('working')
        try {
            // create token
            const response = await this.props.stripe.createToken();
            token = response.token.id;
            await strapi.createEntry('order', {
                address,
                city,
                products: checkOutItems,
                amount,
                token
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Well I am expecting that when i fill out the form as well as the chain of '4242' for stripe card element on the page, the charge will be sent and i can go to my stripe dashboard and see the charge, and also be able to go to my strapi admin dashboard and go to orders and see a new order created.

As of now, none of this happens. I fill the information, click submit, the form resets and then nothing. No error is logged, no console.logs within the try catch will work.

Comment: You likely need to prevent the form's default submit functionality by calling `preventDefault()` on the event in the click handler.

Comment: @taintedzodiac you are the best!